# How to get a list of installed android applications and pick one to run

Tags: android, android-intent

I asked a similar question to this earlier this week but I'm still not understanding how to get a list of all installed applications and then pick one to run.

I've tried:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
```

and this only shows application that are preinstalled or can run the `ACTION_MAIN` Intent type.

I also know I can use `PackageManager` to get all the installed applications, but how do I use this to run a specific application?

Comment: How can you only get the information about the picked app in the list ?

Comment: Are you trying to start a specific set of apps, like, a gallery app. Or a set of apps that can offer you a service, like getting a file?

Answer (score 295, accepted):

Following is the code to get the list of activities/applications installed on Android :

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

You will get all the necessary data in the `ResolveInfo` to start a application. You can check `ResolveInfo` javadoc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html).

Comment: How can I start one of these? I got the activityInfo inside ResolveInfo, but I can't manage to start it.

Comment: Nevermind, found it. I should create a new Intent using the full class name (package + class).

Comment: How can you only get the information about the picked app in the list ?

Comment: I wanted to understand the android /play store policy about the my app reading and storing a list of all apps, and potentially communicating with a server. Is there any guidelines?

Comment: @Karan how can we find the default file manager's package name from the list? Any idea/solution ?

Comment: @dowjones123 Did u happen to find the guidelines regarding this ?

Comment: VersionName? Did I miss?

Comment: can I filter paid and unpaid apps?

Comment: can we access getPackageManager from a service?

Comment: this solution didn't work on target SDK 31

Answer (score 468):

Here's a cleaner way using the `PackageManager`

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
//get a list of installed apps.
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
    Log.d(TAG, "Source dir : " + packageInfo.sourceDir);
    Log.d(TAG, "Launch Activity :" + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName)); 
}
// the getLaunchIntentForPackage returns an intent that you can use with startActivity()
```

More info here http://qtcstation.com/2011/02/how-to-launch-another-app-from-your-app/

Comment: Works gr8.
But when tried this on Android 4.0.3, nothing gets printed !!
Any clue ??

Comment: Make sure you are not filtering out debug log statements.

Comment: This code is working however, do you have any idea on how to put those list of application in a ListView?

Comment: @androidBoomer im doing the same. read this here - http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: @DavidT. I already figured it out. Now, I'm working on how can I access those installed app in order to create a shortcut inside my App. Is that possible?

Comment: @androidBoomer i think so. you should be able to get each app's icons, and then launch them based on the intent that they specified to accept. you can ask as a question, and tag me for me to answer. i don't have much space here (commenting) to answer.

Comment: @DavidT. here's my question. I really need your help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371491/create-app-shortcut-inside-the-custom-launcher-in-android

Comment: This works great but can take a few seconds depending on the number of apps installed. Is there a faster way to load this?

Comment: @Nelson Ramirez is it possible to find memory size consumed by each installed app ? how can i find  ?

Comment: I have tried this on Andriod 6.0 it still shows an application as installed after it has been uninstalled.

Comment: qtfstation link isn't working. I'm wondering if anyone could shed light on what the GET_META_DATA constant does, specifically?

Comment: @user10186832 are you sure you didn't input MATCH_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES?

Comment: @JohnyTex I think it depends on what the uninstall procedure does

Comment: Yes if you do pm uninstall -k (I think it is) then it keeps the userdata, meaning it should show up even when uninstalled, but to my understanding only if you input MATCH_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES...

Answer (score 67):

Another way to filter on system apps (works with the example of king9981):

```
/**
 * Return whether the given PackageInfo represents a system package or not.
 * User-installed packages (Market or otherwise) should not be denoted as
 * system packages.
 * 
 * @param pkgInfo
 * @return
 */
private boolean isSystemPackage(PackageInfo pkgInfo) {
    return ((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0);
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer for filtering out system apps.

Comment: But I t filters appliaction like settings , maps , or ... , how to list them too

Comment: The "? true : false" part of your return statement is redundant

Comment: simplify return ((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0);

Comment: how to filter paid apps?

Comment: Thumbs down for using a bitwise operator with a != :(

Comment: @Ondrej Sotolar What do you suggest?  I see there are unneeded parentheses, but I don't understand your comment.

Comment: It's just a matter of style. For me, bitwise operators break readability big time. Instead of just flying through a simple if statement I have to actually stop and think about the implications of the operator.

Comment: This is not working in case of samsung devices. becasuse it is counting facebook app as systems signed appp

Answer (score 63):

Here a good example:

```
class PInfo {
    private String appname = "";
    private String pname = "";
    private String versionName = "";
    private int versionCode = 0;
    private Drawable icon;
    private void prettyPrint() {
        Log.v(appname + "\t" + pname + "\t" + versionName + "\t" + versionCode);
    }
}

private ArrayList<PInfo> getPackages() {
    ArrayList<PInfo> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
    final int max = apps.size();
    for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
        apps.get(i).prettyPrint();
    }
    return apps;
}

private ArrayList<PInfo> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
    ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<PInfo>();        
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
            continue ;
        }
        PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();
        newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
        newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
        newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
        newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
        res.add(newInfo);
    }
    return res; 
}
```

Comment: How do you execute one of those if you need to? I mean, can you get the Intent?

Comment: Great. Thanks for your answer. I have used your answer in my application and I have a small problem with the size of icon. most of them are normal and some of them are very big or small. How can I fix that. Do you have any idea? thanks

Answer (score 42):

**Getting list of installed non-system apps**

```
public static void installedApps()
{
    List<PackageInfo> packList = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for (int i=0; i < packList.size(); i++)
    {
        PackageInfo packInfo = packList.get(i);
        if (  (packInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0)
        {
            String appName = packInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
            Log.e("App № " + Integer.toString(i), appName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

To filter on sytem based apps :

```
private boolean isSystemPackage(ResolveInfo ri) {
    return (ri.activityInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 19):

To get all installed apps you can use Package Manager

```
List<PackageInfo> apps = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
```

To run an app, you can use its package name

```
Intent launchApp = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(“package name”)
startActivity(launchApp);
```

For more detail you can read this blog http://codebucket.co.in/android-get-list-of-all-installed-apps/

Comment: This is more to the point. We can set a proper check by finding out our required app.

Answer (score 18):

`context.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);` 
Should return the list of all the installed apps but in **android 11** it'll only return the list of system apps. To get the list of all the applications(system+user) we need to provide an additional permission to the application i.e

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>`

Comment: small corrections: 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>

Answer (score 15):

You can Find the List of installed apps in Android Device by using below code, "packageInfo" Contains Installed Application Information
in Device. we can retrive Intent for the application installed from
the packageinfo object and by using startactivity(intent), can start
application. it is up to you how you organize the UI either Listview
or Gridview. so on click event based on position, you can retrive intent
object and start activity intent.

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);


for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) 

{
 if(pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName)!= null &&   

                   !pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName).equals(""))


{

    System.out.println("Package Name :" + packageInfo.packageName);

    System.out.println("Launch Intent For Package :"   +  
                  pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName));

    System.out.println("Application Label :"   + pm.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo));

    System.out.println("Application Label :"   + 
                           pm.getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.packageName).toString());

    System.out.println("i : "+i);

    /*if(i==2)

    {
         startActivity(pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName));

     break;

    }*/

    i++;

}
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I had a requirement to filter out the system apps which user do not really use(eg. "com.qualcomm.service", "update services", etc). Ultimately I added another condition to filter down the app list. I just checked whether the app has 'launcher intent'.

So, the resultant code looks like...

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<ApplicationInfo> apps = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_GIDS);

        for (ApplicationInfo app : apps) {
            if(pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName) != null) {
                // apps with launcher intent
                if((app.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP) != 0) {
                    // updated system apps

                } else if ((app.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) {
                    // system apps

                } else {
                    // user installed apps

                }
                appsList.add(app);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks. The getLaunchIntentForPackage is very useful to get the apps present in the App Drawer :-)

Answer (score 10):

If there are multiple launchers in a one package above code has a problem. Eg: on LG Optimus Facebook for LG, MySpace for LG, Twitter for LG contains in a one package name SNS and if you use above SNS will repeat. After hours of research I came with below code. Seems to work well.

```
private List<String> getInstalledComponentList()
            throws NameNotFoundException {
        final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        List<ResolveInfo> ril = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
        List<String> componentList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String name = null;

        for (ResolveInfo ri : ril) {
            if (ri.activityInfo != null) {
                Resources res = getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(ri.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                if (ri.activityInfo.labelRes != 0) {
                    name = res.getString(ri.activityInfo.labelRes);
                } else {
                    name = ri.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(
                            getPackageManager()).toString();
                }
                componentList.add(name);
            }
        }
        return componentList;
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

Since Android 11 (API level 30), most user-installed apps are not visible by default. You must either statically declare which apps and/or intent filters you are going to get info about in your manifest like this:

```xml
<manifest>
    <queries>
        <!-- Explicit apps you know in advance about: -->
        <package android:name="com.example.this.app"/>
        <package android:name="com.example.this.other.app"/>

        <!-- Intent filter signatures that you are going to query: -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
    
    ...
</manifest>
```

Or require the `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` permission.

After doing the above, the other answers here still apply.

Learn more here:

- [The migration
  documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility)
- [The dedicated documentation page (has more
  information)](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility)
- [The official blog
  post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9)

Answer (score 8):

@Jas:
I don't have that code anymore, but I've found something close. I've made this to search for "components" of my application, they are just activities with a given category.

```
private List<String> getInstalledComponentList() {
    Intent componentSearchIntent = new Intent();
    componentSearchIntent.addCategory(Constants.COMPONENTS_INTENT_CATEGORY);
    componentSearchIntent.setAction(Constants.COMPONENTS_INTENT_ACTION_DEFAULT);
    List<ResolveInfo> ril = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(componentSearchIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    List<String> componentList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Search for installed components found " + ril.size() + " matches.");
    for (ResolveInfo ri : ril) {
        if (ri.activityInfo != null) {
            componentList.add(ri.activityInfo.packageName);// + ri.activityInfo.name);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Found installed: " + componentList.get(componentList.size()-1));
        }
    }
    return componentList;
}
```

I've commented the part where it gets the activity name, but it's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 7):

### Clean solution that filter successfuly out system apps

The idea behind this solution is that the main activity of every system app does not have a *custom activity icon*. This method gives me an excellent result:

```
 public static Set<PackageInfo> getInstalledApps(Context ctx) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = ctx.getPackageManager();

    final List<PackageInfo> allInstalledPackages = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    final Set<PackageInfo> filteredPackages = new HashSet();

    Drawable defaultActivityIcon = packageManager.getDefaultActivityIcon();

    for(PackageInfo each : allInstalledPackages) {
        if(ctx.getPackageName().equals(each.packageName)) {
            continue;  // skip own app
        }

        try {
            // add only apps with application icon
            Intent intentOfStartActivity = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(each.packageName);
            if(intentOfStartActivity == null)
                continue;

            Drawable applicationIcon = packageManager.getActivityIcon(intentOfStartActivity);
            if(applicationIcon != null && !defaultActivityIcon.equals(applicationIcon)) {
                filteredPackages.add(each);
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.i("MyTag", "Unknown package name " + each.packageName);
        }
    }

    return filteredPackages;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
private static boolean isThisASystemPackage(Context context, PackageInfo  packageInfo ) {
        try {
            PackageInfo sys = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("android", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            return (packageInfo != null && packageInfo.signatures != null &&
                    sys.signatures[0].equals(packageInfo.signatures[0]));
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I have another solution:

```
ArrayList<AppInfo> myAppsToUpdate;

    // How to get the system and the user apps.
    public ArrayList<AppInfo> getAppsToUpdate() {

        PackageManager pm = App.getContext().getPackageManager();
        List<ApplicationInfo> installedApps = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
        myAppsToUpdate = new ArrayList<AppInfo>();
        for (ApplicationInfo aInfo : installedApps) {

            if ((aInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) {
                // System apps 
            } else {
                // Users apps
                AppInfo appInfo = new AppInfo();
                appInfo.setAppName(aInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
                appInfo.setPackageName(aInfo.packageName);
                appInfo.setLaunchActivity(pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(aInfo.packageName).toString());
                try {
                    PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo(aInfo.packageName, 0);
                    appInfo.setVersionName(info.versionName.toString());
                    appInfo.setVersionCode("" + info.versionCode);
                    myAppsToUpdate.add(appInfo);
                } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.e("ERROR", "we could not get the user's apps");
                }

            }
        }
        return myAppsToUpdate;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Get All the apps:

```
    PackageManager pm = getContext().getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> apps = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
```

Check if installed app then open:

```
if((app.flags & (ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP | ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)) > 0) {
                String app_package = app.packageName;
Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(app_package);
context.startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer is correct an list of installed app show and search feature add.

**Kotlin**

**activity_all_installed_app.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AllInstalledAppActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalInstalledApp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/total_Installed_Apps"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/totalInstalledApp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/installed_app_layout" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**installed_app_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/app_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_app_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/app_icon"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/app_package"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="@string/app_package_name"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/app_icon"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/list_app_name" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**AppModel.kt**

```
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

class AppModel(private var name:String, private var icon: Drawable, private var packages:String) {
    fun getName(): String {
        return name
    }

    fun getIcon(): Drawable {
        return icon
    }

    fun getPackages(): String {
        return packages
    }
}
```

**AppAdapter.kt**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.materialsouk.allcodeapp.R
import com.materialsouk.allcodeapp.models.AppModel
import java.util.ArrayList

import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.provider.Settings
import android.widget.Toast


class AppAdapter(private val context: Context, private var appModelList: ArrayList<AppModel>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<AppAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


    class ViewHolder(ItemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(ItemView) {
        val appNameTxt: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_app_name)
        val appPackageNameTxt: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.app_package)
        val appIcon: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.app_icon)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view: View =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.installed_app_layout, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.appNameTxt.text = appModelList[position].getName()
        holder.appIcon.setImageDrawable(appModelList[position].getIcon())
        holder.appPackageNameTxt.text = appModelList[position].getPackages()

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val dialogListTitle = arrayOf("Open App", "App Info")
            val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            builder.setTitle("Choose Action")
                .setItems(
                    dialogListTitle
                ) { _, which ->
                    when (which) {
                        0 -> {
                            val intent =
                                context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(appModelList[position].getPackages())
                            if (intent != null) {
                                context.startActivity(intent)
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(context,"System app is not open for any reason.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            }
                        }
                        1 -> {
                            val intent = Intent()
                            intent.action = Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
                            intent.data =
                                Uri.parse("package:${appModelList[position].getPackages()}")
                            context.startActivity(intent)
                        }
                    }
                }
            builder.show()
        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return appModelList.size
    }
}
```

This is menu
**search_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

**AllInstalledAppActivity.kt**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Dialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.materialsouk.allcodeapp.models.AppModel

import android.content.pm.PackageInfo

import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.view.Menu
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
import com.materialsouk.allcodeapp.adapters.AppAdapter
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList


class AllInstalledAppActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var installedAppsList: ArrayList<AppModel>
    private lateinit var installedAppAdapter: AppAdapter

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_installed_app)
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)
        val loadingDialog = Dialog(this)
        loadingDialog.setContentView(R.layout.loading)
        loadingDialog.window!!.setLayout(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
        loadingDialog.setCancelable(false)
        installedAppsList = ArrayList()
        loadingDialog.show()
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            getInstalledApps()
            loadingDialog.dismiss()
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.totalInstalledApp).text =
                "${getString(R.string.total_Installed_Apps)} ${installedAppsList.size}"
            installedAppAdapter = AppAdapter(this, installedAppsList)
            recyclerView.adapter = installedAppAdapter
        }, 500)

    }

    @SuppressLint("QueryPermissionsNeeded")
    private fun getInstalledApps(): ArrayList<AppModel> {
        installedAppsList.clear()
        val packs = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0)
        for (i in packs.indices) {
            val p = packs[i]
            if (!isSystemPackage(p)) {
                val appName = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString()
                val icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(packageManager)
                val packages = p.applicationInfo.packageName
                installedAppsList.add(AppModel(appName, icon, packages))
            }
        }
        installedAppsList.sortBy { it.getName().capitalized() }
        return installedAppsList
    }
    private fun String.capitalized(): String {
        return this.replaceFirstChar {
            if (it.isLowerCase())
                it.titlecase(Locale.getDefault())
            else it.toString()
        }
    }
    private fun isSystemPackage(pkgInfo: PackageInfo): Boolean {
        return pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags and ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM != 0
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu)
        val search = menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search)

        val searchView = search.actionView as SearchView
        searchView.maxWidth = android.R.attr.width
        searchView.queryHint = "Search app name or package"
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                val appModelArrayList: ArrayList<AppModel> = ArrayList()

                for (i in installedAppsList) {
                    if (i.getName().lowercase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(
                            newText!!.lowercase(
                                Locale.getDefault()
                            )
                        )
                        ||
                        i.getPackages().lowercase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(
                            newText.lowercase(
                                Locale.getDefault()
                            )
                        )
                    ) {
                        appModelArrayList.add(i)
                    }
                }
                installedAppAdapter =
                    AppAdapter(this@AllInstalledAppActivity, appModelArrayList)

                recyclerView.adapter = installedAppAdapter
                installedAppAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                return true
            }
        })

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
fun getInstalledApps(context: Context): List<ApplicationInfo> {
    val result: ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> = arrayListOf()
    val userManager = context.getSystemService(Context.USER_SERVICE) as UserManager
    val launcherApps = context.getSystemService(Context.LAUNCHER_APPS_SERVICE) as LauncherApps

    for (profile in userManager.userProfiles) {
        for (app in launcherApps.getActivityList(null, profile)) {
            result.add(app.applicationInfo)
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

Add this permission to Manifest File

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
                List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
                for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) 
                {
                   if ((app.activityInfo.name).contains("facebook")) 
                   {
                     // facebook  
                   }

                   if ((app.activityInfo.name).contains("android.gm")) 
                   {
                     // gmail  
                   }

                   if ((app.activityInfo.name).contains("mms")) 
                   {
                     // android messaging app
                   }

                   if ((app.activityInfo.name).contains("com.android.bluetooth")) 
                   {
                     // android bluetooth  
                   }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<ApplicationInfo> getApplications(Context context) {
    return context.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps, updated function to get all system, system apps which are updated and user-installed apps.

```
fun installedAppsAndSystemApps() {
    val packageManager = context.packageManager
    val packList = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0)
    val installedApps = ArrayList<PackageInfo>()
    val updatedSystemApps = ArrayList<PackageInfo>()
    val systemApps = ArrayList<PackageInfo>()

    for (i in packList.indices) {
        val packInfo = packList[i]
        if (packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packInfo.packageName) != null) {
            when {
                packInfo.applicationInfo.flags and ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP != 0 -> {
                    // updated system apps
                    updatedSystemApps.add(packInfo)
                }
                packInfo.applicationInfo.flags and ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM != 0 -> {
                    // system apps
                    systemApps.add(packInfo)
                }
                else -> {
                    // user installed apps
                    installedApps.add(packInfo)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For android version 11 and above please use below permission to show all the installed apps.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Google now provides [LauncherApps](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/LauncherApps) API for fetching information about all the launchable activities in Android. We can use it to fetch the list of all the apps installed on the device.

Query Permission to be added in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
```

Method for fetching all the installed apps information.

```kotlin
val launcherApps = context.getSystemService(LauncherApps::class.java)

// Get the list of launcher activity info
val activityList = launcherApps.getActivityList(null, Process.myUserHandle())

// Print total apps count
Log.d("MainActivity", "Total Apps: ${activityList.size}")
```

`getActivityList` returns a list of [LauncherActivityInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/LauncherActivityInfo) objects which contains info like first install time, drawable app icon, app label, etc.

Hope it helps!