# How to find installed application's name in device?

Tags: android

I will develop an android application,so i need one help form you,i want to find  `what are the applications are installed in our device and i want to uninstalled by given application name by user using Intent`.How is possible?

Thanks All

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list the existing applications. [Check This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746)

This blog [post](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=98) may be helpful for uninstalling applications: