# How to detect Application by application name(not package name) which is installed or not in android device?

Tags: android

> I want to detect application by application name (not application
>   package name) is installed or not in android device. If there is any
>   way to detect application from application name please help me and
>   provide some logic or method.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327710/how-to-find-installed-applications-name-in-device

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean isAppInstalled(String appName){
        PackageManager pkgMan = getPackageManager();
        List<PackageInfo> pkgList= pkgMan.getInstalledPackages(0);
        for(int a=0;a<pkgList.size();a++){
            if(appName.equals(pkgMan.getApplicationLabel(pkgList.get(a).applicationInfo))){
                return true;
            }//if app name match needed name
        }//for loop
        return false;
    }
```