# Accessing basic data on installed Apps

Tags: android, list, caching

I'm fairly new to Android/Java and wanted to make an app that displays info on the installed apps on a device.

I've successfully used resolveInfo to get an app list as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run).

But I was interested in determining things like the app category, current cache size, or last time the app was used.  I thought I could access this using /data/data/, but I guess I can't do that due to security issues.

Any coding magic that can get this kind of information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> app category

That is an Android Market concept and does not exist in the Android OS.

> current cache size

I suspect that is not available to SDK applications.

> last time the app was used

I am not even sure that is tracked.

> I thought I could access this using /data/data/, but I guess I can't do that due to security issues.

Correct.

Comment: Eh, that's what I thought.  Disappointing!  But how does an app like DiskUsage determine data size of other apps if /data/data is unavailable...

Comment: @kittka: DiskUsage reports on external storage (e.g., SD card), not `/data/data`.