# android: How to populate a spinner with a string[] which is a list of installed packages?

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

```
 final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    final List pkgAppsList = this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
    final String[] apps = (String[]) pkgAppsList.toArray();
    Spinner appSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> appAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, apps, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    appAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    appSpinner.setAdapter(cloudAdapter);
```

The previous code is throwing out errors for me in eclipse. I understand how to get the list of installed apps, and I understand how to populate a spinner using the createFromResource method. However I've never attempted to do so in this manner? Anyone able to direct me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you post the error here. So we can see what is going wrong?

Comment: I know it's late, but still...There's no ArrayAdapter that accepts a list of objects as its 2nd arg.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named `arrays.xml` inside `values` folder.

Inside that give:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="array_name">
        <item>value1</item>
        <item>value2</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Then inside your spinner,give:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.array_name, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope this may work for you.

Comment: I am aware of how to do this. I'm trying to populate the spinner with an array created programmatically from the list of installed apps....

Answer (score 0):

Check : [How to get a list of installed android applications and pick one to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run/2696617#2696617)

Answer (score 0):

Eventough it is late, you should use this constructor of `ArrayAdapter` instead :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> appAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, apps);
appAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
appSpinner.setAdapter(appAdapter);
```