# Android Listen to Installation Notification

Tags: android, installation, google-play

Google show in the notification menu percents of installation process. Does it possible to listen to it. I want f.e. receive the begining of installation process and the ending. I know that ending can be received with `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED` . But how can I get information about starting of installation or is some apps downloaded in this time from play store?

Answer (score 1):

> Does it possible to listen to it.

No. You cannot spy on other applications' `Notifications`.

> But how can I get information about starting of installation or is some apps downloaded in this time from play store?

You modify the firmware to add this capability and install this firmware on your own device.

Comment: Are there really no possibilities to identify that android market download some apps? Something like DownloadManager must be implemented in Android and he must have some queries of downloads?

Comment: @Aprel: Of course not. That would be a massive security hole, of primary interest to malware authors.

Comment: I just found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941100/how-to-get-a-list-of-applications-being-download and it seams not to be security hole!

Comment: @Aprel: You will not be able to use that to find out about an installation any sooner than you would via `PACKAGE_ADDED`. Moreover, as Ms. Hackborn noted, the Play Store app may stop using `DownloadManager` at any time. And, there are many other ways of downloading and installing apps that will not use `DownloadManager`.

Answer (score 0):

this might be possible on API 18 (android 4.3 jelly bean) :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html#43-beautiful-apps

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html#NotificationListener

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2013/07/android-43-and-updated-developer-tools.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20blogspot/hsDu%20%28Android%20Developers%20Blog%29