# How do I list all of the applications installed on an Android mobile?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a list of installed android applications and pick one to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run)

I have a button. I gave it a click event. Now, I want to list the installed applications on my Android mobile. Is there any possible way to do this using intents? If anyone knows, please tell me.

Comment: This article should help you: http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PackageManager class's **getInstalledApplications()** [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledApplications%28int%29) and take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledApplications%28int%29).