# how to retrieve icon of application file extension is associated with

Tags: android, file, icons, file-association

The file manager named "File manager" does this for example. If I browse to the dir with my movies, they will be displayed with the Gallery icon as they open with that app by default. But when I install a new movie player, the icon will change to that of the player. 
So how would I go about retrieving the icon associated to each file (the application it opens with)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could (untested);

Take all installed applications (using `PackageManager`):

[How to get a list of installed android applications and pick one to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run)

Take an icon for a specific application:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageItemInfo.html#icon

Hope it helps.