# How do I filter out applications from system packages

Tags: android, android-emulator

Alrright here's what I'm trying to do. I'm using this code:

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    if ((packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 1)
    {
        //irrelevant code here
    }
}
```

To filter out the system packages from the user applications for an application launcher. The problem with this approach is that it also filters out apps like the Camera app. What can I do so that it doesn't exclude these apps that are somewhat essential to be in an application launcher but are already part of the Android OS?

I hope you understood what I'm trying to say...

Comment: Did you find the solution? i am also facing the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

The [following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29855596/716027) worked for me.

Instead of

```
(packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 1
```

use

```
pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName) != null
```