# Activity container in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, containers

I am making an application based on a ListView layout. Each item in the ListView launches a different application. The problem is that applications do not know what I have in the beginning. So the process of adding an activity should be almost automatic. This problem can be solved?. Think of an application container. Sorry for my English.
 Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extends the ActivityGroup class for this. You can get the basic idea for this class by referring this link.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html

Comment: hello, thank you very much for answering so fast. I have another question, with Activity group, I can add applications complete, with their Manifest, so with full apk. That would be the idea. Develop applications separately and add them automatically to a container. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to give the reference of other project file to your project?

Comment: Hi, I want to have all applications inside the project.

Comment: Use the PackageManager class this can give u the package name, App name of the all installed apps, put all app's names in arraylist and this array list u can use to populate in ur listview. use the   OnItemClickListener interface for listview item click and pass the itent to the particular package.This link give u the better idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run