# Check whether application is installed or uninstalled

Tags: android

Can I define that application was installed earlier? For example I can check whether application is installed or not installed but if application was installed and later was uninstalled. Is there way to check it or not?

Comment: you can check using package name. here is [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run

Comment: other link http://www.coderanch.com/t/492490/Android/Mobile/Check-if-application-installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phone does not store any information about the uninstalled app. If ur app has a backend, then try saving UDID in the server when app is installed. So that u can check next time whether the app is once installed and uninstalled in a phone. But if ur app is a stand alone app with out any server, u cant do that.

Comment: getDeviceId() from TelephonyManager

Comment: How would you find out that your app has be uninstalled from a device?

Comment: U cant find it. Sorry, Currently android does not has it.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalled apps are per default leaving no trace on the phone.

If it is your own app you want to check whether was installed and later uninstalled you could code your app to leave a trace, either on a server (sending the phone ID to the server) or on the SD Card. Both methods requires permissions.

If it isnt your own app you want to check whether was installed and later uninstalled you are out of luck, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a file on the SD card when the application is installed the first time.

Then when it's reinstalled, your application will check the presence of this file.

Comment: If the user deletes that file, how can u check?

Answer (score 0):

If you are supporting FCM in your app .
Than have a look at the server side api for sending the notifications
If sending fails to a user , we can consider that user has uninstalled the app.
Have a look at the following article.

https://medium.com/what-is-singleton-pattern-and-why-we-need-them/how-to-track-uninstalled-users-from-app-using-fcm-afdba7301116

I haven't gone though backend apis for FCM. not sure whether we get this info while pushing out a notification to a single user or a group of users.

my intention is that try for FCM if it useful for you to determine the install/uninstall status