# Open dialog when package cannot be started?

Tags: android, button, android-activity, dialog

I am currently developing an app that can open my other app within a button click.
However, when the targeted app is not already installed, the app will crash and force close. How do I set it up so that it shows up a dialog and gives a link to install the app?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is query the installed packages via an intent call as seen here: [How to get a list of installed android applications and pick one to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run). Then just cycle through the list and see if your app is there.

Comment: Thats not the main problem. What I want is the activity to open up a dialog when the package is not installed. I know theres a method like "if package is opened, done", "if else, show dialog"(something like that). I will need to use this in future projects also. But thanks for the comment.

Comment: @borislemke Right, you use the above method to discover whether or not a package is installed. Then open your dialog as you say to inform the user that the package is not installed. Also, in reference to your third sentence, there is a huge distinction between "installed" and "open". What do you want the trigger to be? Open or installed?

Comment: If the app is already installed, it should be OPENing the app. But when the app is not present, it should open a dialog that gives the user an option to install the app via a market link.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I'll to do with ur method. Hope I'll get it to work

Comment: Anyway, there shouldnt be a need to scroll through a list, everything should work automatically.

Comment: Yes, and you have to program the automatically. If you then want it to start the already installed app, you just call its intent, I believe.