# check to see if an application is a service or contentprovider

Tags: android, android-service, shortcut, android-contentprovider

I am writing an application to add all our apps to the homescreen of our devices. I need it to skip the apps that are services or contentproviders that just run in the background and are never "launched" by the user.

Any ideas? Right now i am specifying the apps, but would like to have it more automated.

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run

Comment: Already have looked over that, the answers given still grab all the services and contentproviders. The main answer that i tested was given by Nelson Ramirez.

Comment: Weird, it shouldn't since it's using the `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`. Lemme think some more.

Comment: I am about to try what Karan said. I actually have not tried it yet.

Comment: Can you look at the returned `ResolveInfo` and see if `activityInfo` is non-null? Should be non-null for Activity classes and null for others.

Comment: The post from Karan on the other post worked. Could you post your suggestions and link as an answer so that i can accept it please. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Sure, thanks for thinking of it :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run) for information on finding launchable `Intent` instances from the package manager.