# How to launch android music store from ap?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play, google-music

Right now I'm using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://music"));
startActivity(intent);
```

to launch the music store in the android market which seems to crash. Also how could I include a search string in this. If it is even possible that is.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to launch Market at the [Google Music application](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.music)?

If so, you can use this code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.music"));
startActivity(i);
```

**Edit:** ... Or are you trying to launch Market at the Music section? I don't think it's possible. Also, many users can't access the Music store in Market, so it won't work for those users (which is basically anyone outside the US).

Comment: Actually thats not what I meant but that is very interesting, is there a way to see if google music is installed or not before launching the intent? What I meant however was when you first open the market on android there are now three options: apps, music, and books. I want it to take you to where you would be if you clicked on music

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Regarding a way to see if an app is installed, you can refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run

Comment: Google music is also only available in the U.S btw

Comment: I just noticed that in google music ap you can click an icon and it takes you to the music section of the market so this is possible

Comment: Hmm, I don't see that. Where's the icon?

Comment: Int the bottom right next to the search button there is a market logo which takes you to the music section. Is google music open source?

Comment: Hmm, doesn't appear on my Music app. Must be because I'm outside the US. I'm afraid I don't know if it's open source or not, but I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to launch the market in music mode, try using `https://market.android.com/music`. If you want to do search for specific music, try `https://market.android.com/search?q=sting&c=music`

Comment: This is a last resort option, the website is not formatted for mobile and is very hard to navigate on a small screen

Comment: The reason I asked you if you tried these is that ideally, the Android Market app should be intercepting the `https://market.android.com` URLs. In general, `https://market.android.com/music` should be equal to `market://music`. (On a side note, if that's implemented properly, it'll likely lead to the same crash. :-/)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found this somewhere on the net and it works!

```
public void buyMusic(View v){
     Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=album-Bbeyjqldhuyoda7byal4op4he2u");
     Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
     startActivity(it);
}
```

Comment: This however only works for individual albums. I need the homepage