# List out installed/running applications in android programmatically

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a list of installed android applications and pick one to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run)

We have using a android mobile.

1. How to list out `All Installed Applications`.
2. How to list out `All Running Applications`.

Help Me. Thanks.

Comment: How to list out all applications through programmatically?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**To get the list of activities/applications installed on Android:**

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

Referred from: [How to get a list of installed android applications and pick one to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run)

**To check all running applications**

```
ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager)
this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

Referred From: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/138412-android-20-list-of-running-applications/

**Note: Above described function will return correct result for below API 21, for 21 and above it's deprecated.**

Comment: Thanks. It's list out all the applications. How do identify to list out currently running applications through programmatically?

Comment: Thanks Ponmalar. It's usefult to me and others.

Comment: with the above code i am getting all the recent apps,is there any way to filter system apps and list out only recent installed apps

Comment: @Ponmalar I'm obtaining "ActivityManager cannot be resolved to a variable" in ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager); any idea why?

Comment: @Ponmalar I have everything imported btw

Comment: @Ponmalar  can u pls tell me how can i sort system running apps and installed running apps ?

Comment: LIsting running apps in that way will not work for API version >=21, this will return just you application

Comment: @Apperside What is used for same task for API version >=21 ?

Comment: For fetching list of applications for API version >= 21, we can use the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77113333/4511489).