# Monitoring of the application in android

Tags: android

Good day. Can I use the android sdk to get the name of an android application in which the user is working, and the session-time in this application. i.e. service will receive the name of the application and a session and send it to the database.

Solved. Here is my soulution

```
 private String getRunningAppByActivity(){
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        // get the info from the currently running task
        List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);

        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        String name=componentInfo.getPackageName();

        final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        ApplicationInfo ai;
        try {
            ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(name, 0);
        } catch (final PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            ai = null;
        }
        final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");
        Log.d("APPLICATION_NAME", applicationName);
        return applicationName;
    }
```

Comment: show us your code! <<< you see what I mean?

Comment: there are tons of similar questions. Research a little :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391451/list-out-installed-running-applications-in-android-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
     ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)            
     {context}.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
     List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    final PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();

    for (RunningTaskInfo task : tasks) {

    try {
        ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(task.baseActivity.getPackageName(), 0);
       } catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
    ai = null;
     }
      String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai): "(unknown)");

    }
```

Comment: excuse me, but it will show packages names and also activities, but i need only names

Comment: i cant get package names of running tasks, but how can i know the name of app whose activity is opened right now?