# How could I get all applications that were installed by user?

Tags: android

How could I get all applications that were installed by user?

I want to develop an app that can present all applications that were installed by user, but

I don't understand how to get them.

use `getExternalStorageDirectory()`?

or is there have other method?

Comment: I assume this is Android, by that function name? Please tag it. What you're asking is very much different on a Windows machine, or on a Mac box, or on a Symbian phone.

Comment: perhaps reading this question- answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
 final Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
 final List mylist= context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
```