# how to call Dictionary app using Android Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, dictionary

I have a Dictionary.com App installed on my mobile.
I am creating another app and would like to know how to interact with Dictionary app using Intent.

If there is any way then please let me know

Answer (score 1):

You can just call your dictionary app from your app in this way..

here com.example.package.ActivityToStart defines your dictionary app

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("com.example.package", "com.example.package.ActivityToStart");
startActivity(intent);
```

another best method is

```
try{
   PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
   Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.package");
   startActivity(intent);
}catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you don't know the package name of your dictionary app just check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5097838/1265724)

Comment: Be aware that you must `try {} catch {}` second option in case packet doesn't exist ( NameNotFoundException )

Comment: ok. i too accept with @fliespl suggetion. thanks for your information

Comment: thanks guys I am able to view the package and call Dictionary app...