# Get the launcher Activity name of an android application

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to get the name of launcher activity to launch the activity from my application.
Any solution

Comment: ComponentName name = new ComponentName(Package,launcheractivity);
    
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
 | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
i.setComponent(name);
_context.startActivity(i);


Here I want name of launcheractivity for ComponentName..

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5097838/318508), it lists the required information for all installed apps.

Comment: Launcher activity of any specific app or all installed apps?

Comment: Launcher activity of installed apps

Comment: if you hv the package name then why dont you try directly my code .

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the following code to get the launcher activity of all packages:

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

List<ResolveInfo> appList = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
Collections.sort(appList, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));

for (ResolveInfo temp : appList) {
    Log.v("my logs", "package and activity name = "
            + temp.activityInfo.packageName + "    "
            + temp.activityInfo.name);
}
```

Answer (score 63):

late but the better way it will give the exact intent to launch an activity

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent intent=pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pacakgeName);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Add `Intent` flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` to clear back stack.

Answer (score 19):

Even though the answers above answer directly the OP's question I would like to add my two cents:

```
/** Backwards compatible method that will clear all activities in the stack. */
public void startLauncherActivity(Context context) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
    ComponentName componentName = intent.getComponent();
    Intent mainIntent = IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(componentName);
    context.startActivity(mainIntent);
}
```

Here I do not only get the launcher activity of the application, but also am clearing all the backstack of the activities (which is what I actually needed when I triggered the launcher activity). I call this in case of expired auth token for example.

Important thing is to use `IntentCompat`, otherwise one has to resort to `Intent` flag [`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK), which is introduced only in API 11.

Comment: Your 2 cents were very helpful :)

Comment: Google has removed the method `IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask()`, use `Intent.makeRestartActivityTask()` instead

Answer (score 3):

This is the easiest  solution you can use. And it works perfectly.`

```
private String getLauncherActivityName(){
        String activityName = "";
        final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName());
        List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent,0);
        if(activityList != null){
            activityName = activityList.get(0).activityInfo.name;
        }
        return activityName;
    }
```