# How to hide other apps from my app when querying PackageManager?

Tags: android

I want to hide any application (Telegram, Viber,  ...) from my app Android. I want to hide another apps in list installed apps from my app. I try with this code.
I getting app package name and its activity name using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13027415/208273) by Praful Bhatnagar:

```
private void hideapplication() {
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

List<ResolveInfo> appList = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
Collections.sort(appList, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));

TextView textview= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
 ImageView imageview =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);

for (ResolveInfo temp: appList) {
    Log.v("my logs", "package and activity name = " + temp.activityInfo.packageName + "    " + temp.activityInfo.name);
}
```

}

Use this package name & activity name in below code:

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(applicationInfo.packageName, applicationInfo.name);
        packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
}
```

});

But I am getting force close. How can I solve this problem? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to hide another apps in list installed apps from my app

Fortunately, this is not possible, except via a custom ROM or probably a rooted device.

You can do something similar to this via Android at Work, but your app would need to be a device owner, which requires that your app be set up as part of first powering on the device.

> Use this package name & activity name in below code:

Your app does not have the rights to change the enabled status of components of other apps.

Comment: really? but how does https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thinkyeah.apphider&hl=en work?

Comment: @HomaSh: The English product description has "(Root Required)".