# How to log Launcher Activity name for a Activity?

Tags: android, logging

I need to log the launcher Activity name for a particular activity in android.

I have tried using the code given in " [Get the launcher Activity name of an android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027374/get-the-launcher-activity-name-of-an-android-application)" by doing few modifications like ..
1) I have created a Class called as launcherActivity.
2) In that class I have created a method called as getLauncherActivity().
3) When I try to call this method in another class it is showing null Object reference.

```
public class LauncherActivity {

    public String getLauncherActivity(Context context){
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am calling this method has

```
String launcheractivity=launcherActivity.getLauncherActivity(ctx);
```

What all changes I need to do to log this launcheractivity name.
So please do give Suggestions...

Thank You in Advance:)

Comment: try `String launcheractivity=this.getClass();`

Comment: Why are you returning null ?

Comment: if i try to return intent it is showing it is showing error has required string but returning intent

Answer (score 0):

First of all, activity doesn't have a launcher activity. An application have launcher activity. If you want to know the name of all the launcher activity of all apps installed in your phone. Then you can get it by code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13027415/7045328)

Comment: I will try using this.Thank You

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you need.

```
public String getLauncherActivity(Context context){
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        Intent intent =    packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
        String lname=intent.getComponent().getClassName();
        Log.e("luncher",lname);
        return lname;
```

Comment: if i write this code in separate class .then i need to call this method from another class sooo first do i need to create a private Context ctx .  Then use String LauncherActivity=launcheractivity.getLauncherActivity(ctx);.Is this correct?

Comment: but i am getting null object reference

Comment: show me yours logs if you can and how the code of your class

Comment: show me yours logs if you can and  the code of your class

Comment: can we call the method from anywhere in the program or do we need to follow some procedure to  call method

Comment: anywhere ou have  valide context (Activity, Fragment , Service) or a way to get the context to pass to  the method