# Is there an API to get the apps bought by user from Google Play Store?

Tags: android

I was wondering is there a way to get the apps user bought from Google Play Store or pretty much all the applications. Ofcourse this would need user permission but is there any api which can be used to fetch this information ?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no official API for getting all user activity on the Google Play store, outside of your own application.  However, you **can** use technologies like LVL and/or in-app-billing APIs to determine whether a user has purchased your own app, from within your own app.

Comment: Then how does this app do it: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.azefsw.purchasedapps ?

Answer (score -1):

You can get all installed applications. Look the answer of Nelson Ramirez: [How to get a list of installed android applications and pick one to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run)