# phonegap / cordova android list of installed application

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using cordova 2.2 to create an android application. I'd like to create a html page in which, using javascript, there is the list of the installed  application in the device. How can I do it?

Comment: You will need a PhoneGap/Cordova plugin for this. If there is not an existing plugin, you will have to write one.

Comment: did you find the correct plugin for this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe the Cordova API can provide this information for you. As CommonsWare pointed out you will need a plugin to fetch this information. Here is a link to how to get a list of installed applications.

[How to get a list of installed android applications and pick one to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run)

Here's a [link](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/extending-phonegap-with-native-plugins-for-android.html) for creating an Android plugin

Answer (score 0):

There's this plugin that provides exactly what you're looking for:
https://github.com/weelion/phonegap-plugin-installed-apps

Answer (score 0):

You could use [cordova-plugin-intent-list](https://github.com/nick-denry/cordova-plugin-intent-list) for now. To get installed apps list with icons:

```
navigator.IntentList.getList(function(applist) {
    console.log(applist);
}, function(errorMesssage) {
    console.log(errorMesage);
});
```

`applist` will contain:

```
{
    "label": "Chrome",
    "package": "com.android.chrome",
    "packageIcon": "data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJAAAACQ..."
},
...
```