# Android get a list of all installed apps

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I have obtained a list of installed app using this code:

```
public List<ResolveInfo>() {
    PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
    Intent main=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);

    main.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    List<ResolveInfo> launchables=pm.queryIntentActivities(main, 0);

}
```

There is only a problem: it list only apps that has a MAIN activity.
How can I get a List of all installed apps?
Note that I used this code in a project that need that the List is of ResolveInfo, so please answer only code that returns a List of ResolveInfo.

Comment: Well, I didn't downvote it, but for starters, what you want is impossible. You cannot get a list of installed applications in the form of a `List` of `ResolveInfo` objects.

Comment: You likely got downvoted because your last sentence could be interpreted as a "give me code" request, rather than "please help me with my existing code." I didn't downvote either, but if I had to guess that may be why.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried with:

```
 List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm
            .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

(found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5097838/1668144))

Answer (score 4):

Your question doesn't quite make sense; you're making a bit of an unreasonable request. You say you want a list of all installed apps, but you also want a `List` of `ResolveInfo` objects. The [docs of `ResolveInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html) describe it as:

> Information that is returned from resolving an intent against an IntentFilter.

Apps and `IntentFilter`s don't correlate one to one. What would you want the `ResolveInfo` objects to contain? If there's more than one for a package, which one would you want?

`PackageManager` does include a method [`getInstalledApplications`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledApplications%28int%29), but it returns a `List` of `ApplicationInfo` objects which is a more appropriate type for this sort of query. Likewise there's a [`getInstalledPackages`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledPackages%28int%29) method as well that returns a `List` of `PackageInfo` objects.