# how to get a list of installed app names on phone and display them in a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to create an activity where a ListView shows all the installed apps names with a check box for each name, but I'm not quite sure how to do this since i am new to android development and do not know how to pass data like this to a ListView. Would appreciate any help possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6165023/115145 http://stackoverflow.com/q/14510171/115145 http://stackoverflow.com/q/28542299/115145

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> applist= context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0);
```

you can get it with this code