# get Installed apps from package name

Tags: android, android-activity, package-managers

i have tried the code i pasted below ..but that gives me every application installed but then i need to check each of the app is mine or not by checking with the package name...Is there a code to where i can pass the package name to the phone system so that it gives me all the apps installed based on that package name.

```
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        final List<ResolveInfo> apps = manager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
        Collections.sort(apps, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(manager));
        ArrayList<String> oArrInstalledHomeApps = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (apps != null) 
        {
            final int count = apps.size();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
            {
                ResolveInfo info = apps.get(i);
                String strpackageName = info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;
if(strpackageName.contains ("com.ZZ."))
{
                oArrInstalledHomeApps.add(strpackageName);
}
            }
            return oArrInstalledHomeApps;
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [GetInstalled apps based on package name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955232/getinstalled-apps-based-on-package-name)

Comment: Please do not ask the same question again and again.

Comment: that post has been deleted :(

Comment: It was deleted by you....

Comment: yes thats because i did not make myself clear in that question ..so i deleted it after i posted this one

Comment: Ah alright. However, in the future please use the edit feature to update or rephrase your question, instead of posting a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Theres a cleaner way to do that.

```
 final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        ArrayList<String> oArrInstalledHomeApps = new ArrayList<String>();
        // get a list of installed apps.
        List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
            Log.d(TAG, "Launch Activity :" + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName));
            if (packageInfo.packageName.contains("com.ZZ."))
            {
                oArrInstalledHomeApps.add(packageInfo.packageName);
            }
        }
        return oArrInstalledHomeApps;
```

Copied shamelessly from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run)

Comment: thats my whole point the above code gets all the installed apps and then checks for my package..This takes time ..so how about i send my package name and phone gives me back the installed apps..

Comment: @user1340801 You can't do that. Android doesn't have any search filter like that in PackageManager.

Comment: @RaghavSood thanks..that was i was trying to understand!!!!!..so i need to get all the apps and check for my package ??/ it takes 5-7 secs extra

Comment: Agreed with Rahgav, theres no way to do that. If it takes time, you should display an appropriate dialog that seaerching apps...please wait, something like that. Also it shouldnt run on the UI thread since it may block the app.

Comment: @user1340801 Yeah, that's the only way you'll get this to work. Or you could have a predefined list of package names for your apps, and individually look those up.