# Display package name when app name is clicked in AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android

I have created an AutoCompleteTextView displaying all installed apps.

I have also created a `Toast` (and implemented it to `onItemClickListener`), which will show the **PackageName** of selected app.

How to retrieve package name from package manager? Please help

```
        final AutoCompleteTextView lView;
        final ArrayList results;
        List<ResolveInfo> list;
        final String pname = "";


        results = new ArrayList();
    lView = (AutoCompleteTextView)this.findViewById(R.id.languages);
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();




    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent,
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {
        results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm)
                .toString());
        Log.w("Installed Applications", rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo
                .loadLabel(pm).toString());
    }
    lView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));



    lView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PACKAGENAME", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
  });
```

Comment: I found that post and tried to solve that way but didn't work. I need somebody to help me solve it with my case.

Answer (score 1):

You will get package info from [ResolveInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html).

You have  `List list;`
So change your `ItemClickListener` implementation to this

```
lView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String packageName = list.get(position).activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), packageName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks good, but returns a blank toast (no text)

Comment: Sorry `resolvedPackageName` is optional. You should use `String packageName = list.get(position).activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;` Updated my answer

Comment: This also looks good :D, but returns invalid package (root browser returns com.android.contacts..)

Comment: Is the package name displayed wrong for all intents or only for some?

Comment: It is wrong for all of them

Answer (score 0):

use

```
yourContext.getPackageName();
```

Updated:

**Getting your context:**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ 
        Contenxt yourContext= this;

        yourContext.getPackageName();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I retrieve my context? I mean, what context should I get? Sorry I am a beginner..

getApplicationContext() is right?

Comment: please see answer again, I have updated the answer.

Comment: thanks, but this only inputs the ACTUAL APP package name. As you can see in the code I provided I have an arraylist with a list showing current installed apps. And what I want is that, when any app in the list is selected, the toast will show up its package name

Comment: go throgh this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955414/get-installed-apps-from-package-name