# How to detect whether or not an Android phone has a specific app installed?

Tags: android, detection, smartphone

I've already done this for iPhone app detection, using the meta tag described here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

Now I'm trying to do the same for Droid-app sniffing. Basically, I want to check if the user has the 'sniffing' app installed or not.

Answer (score 1):

*How do I detect whether or not a smartphone has an Android app installed?*

In order to make code work change `"com.your.package.appname.id"` with the application id.

id is the app package and also the market url eg. gmail app url at the market is [`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm) and the id/packagename is `com.google.android.gm`

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Example extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //Put the package name here...
        boolean installed  =   appInstalledOrNot("com.your.package.appname.id");
        if(installed)
        {
                  System.out.println("App already installed om your android");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("App is not installed om your android");
        }
    }
    private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri)
    {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        boolean app_installed = false;
        try
        {
               pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
               app_installed = true;
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
        {
               app_installed = false;
        }
        return app_installed ;
}
}
```

Comment: Umm...where is the getPackageManager() method?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageManager%28%29 it need to be inside an Activity class or called from applicationContext.getPackageManager()

Answer (score 0):

From this: [How to get a list of installed android applications and pick one to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run)

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

Now, from pkgAppList you can see if the app is installed