# How display installed applications in android?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, package, package-managers

Using this code:

```
final PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        //get a list of installed apps.
        List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

        for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
            Log.d(TAG, "Launch Activity :" + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName));
```

I can display in the logcat package infos etc.. But i want display a list in my activity of installed apps with its icon if possible and the name of application. Is it possible?
ps: i'm using fragments

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to launch applications from another application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104942/how-to-launch-applications-from-another-application)

Comment: not at all.. I don't want launch the application but only show a list with icon of app and its name..

Comment: You can use Alex Lockwood Loaders [tutorial](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/09/tutorial-loader-loadermanager.html). Sample app in it shows apps list.

Comment: full tutorial http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/how-to-get-list-of-installed-apps-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

See this demo: 
[Circle launcher](http://developer.samsung.com/android/samples/Circle-Launcher)

Answer (score 0):

Following should do the job of getting the list of applications

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
applications = mPackageManage.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

Comment: but where have i to put this code? i mean, i need a listview right?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

First create a model for **PackageItem**

```
public class PackageItem {

        private Drawable icon;

        private String name;

        private String packageName;

        public String getPackageName() {
            return packageName;
        }

        public void setPackageName(String packageName) {
            this.packageName = packageName;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Drawable getIcon() {
            return icon;
        }

        public void setIcon(Drawable icon) {
            this.icon = icon;
        }
    }
```

Step 2)

**This will give you list of all install application with Application Name,Icon and Package also**

```
public List<PackageItem> getInstalledApplication(){

PackageManager appInfo = getPackageManager();
            List<ApplicationInfo> listInfo = appInfo.getInstalledApplications(0);
            Collections.sort(listInfo, new ApplicationInfo.DisplayNameComparator(appInfo));

            List<PackageItem> data = new ArrayList<PackageItem>();

            for (int index = 0; index < listInfo.size(); index++) {
                try {
                    ApplicationInfo content = listInfo.get(index);
                    if ((content.flags != ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) && content.enabled) {
                        if (content.icon != 0) {
                            PackageItem item = new PackageItem();
                            item.setName(getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(content).toString());
                            item.setPackageName(content.packageName);
                            item.setIcon(getPackageManager().getDrawable(content.packageName, content.icon, content));
                            data.add(item);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
      return data;
   }
```

Now You can use this **List** in your adapter class,

Hope this will help you.

Comment: and, so, have i to create an adapter class? i can't insert theese values in a listview directly?

Comment: @David_D you will show it in ListView, so you need Adapter so that you can present the Application name with Icon.