# How to get the package name of an application and then launch that app using Intent?

Tags: android, android-applicationinfo

I am developing an Android app. In that app, there is a button to go to another activity which contains a list of installed apps on the phone. When the user selects an app, its package name is saved and the user returns to the previous activity. But, how can I get the package name?

```
public class LoaderCustomSupport extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        // Create the list fragment and add it as our sole content.
        if (fm.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
            AppListFragment list = new AppListFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, list).commit();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This class holds the per-item data in our Loader.
     */
    public static class AppEntry {
        public AppEntry(AppListLoader loader, ApplicationInfo info) {
            mLoader = loader;
            mInfo = info;
            mApkFile = new File(info.sourceDir);
        }

        public ApplicationInfo getApplicationInfo() {
            return mInfo;
        }

        public String getLabel() {
            return mLabel;
        }

        public Drawable getIcon() {
            if (mIcon == null) {
                if (mApkFile.exists()) {
                    mIcon = mInfo.loadIcon(mLoader.mPm);
                    return mIcon;
                } else {
                    mMounted = false;
                }
            } else if (!mMounted) {
                // If the app wasn't mounted but is now mounted, reload
                // its icon.
                if (mApkFile.exists()) {
                    mMounted = true;
                    mIcon = mInfo.loadIcon(mLoader.mPm);
                    return mIcon;
                }
            } else {
                return mIcon;
            }

            return mLoader.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(
                android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return mLabel;
        }

        void loadLabel(Context context) {
            if (mLabel == null || !mMounted) {
                if (!mApkFile.exists()) {
                    mMounted = false;
                    mLabel = mInfo.packageName;
                } else {
                    mMounted = true;
                    CharSequence label = mInfo.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager());
                    mLabel = label != null ? label.toString() : mInfo.packageName;
                }
            }
        }

        private final AppListLoader mLoader;
        private final ApplicationInfo mInfo;
        private final File mApkFile;
        private String mLabel;
        private Drawable mIcon;
        private boolean mMounted;
    }

    /**
     * Perform alphabetical comparison of application entry objects.
     */
    public static final Comparator<AppEntry> ALPHA_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<AppEntry>() {
        private final Collator sCollator = Collator.getInstance();

        @Override
        public int compare(AppEntry object1, AppEntry object2) {
            return sCollator.compare(object1.getLabel(), object2.getLabel());
        }
    };

    /**
     * Helper for determining if the configuration has changed in an interesting
     * way so we need to rebuild the app list.
     */
    public static class InterestingConfigChanges {
        final Configuration mLastConfiguration = new Configuration();
        int mLastDensity;

        boolean applyNewConfig(Resources res) {
            int configChanges = mLastConfiguration.updateFrom(res.getConfiguration());
            boolean densityChanged = mLastDensity != res.getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
            if (densityChanged || (configChanges&(ActivityInfo.CONFIG_LOCALE
                    |ActivityInfoCompat.CONFIG_UI_MODE|ActivityInfo.CONFIG_SCREEN_LAYOUT)) != 0) {
                mLastDensity = res.getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Helper class to look for interesting changes to the installed apps
     * so that the loader can be updated.
     */
    public static class PackageIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        final AppListLoader mLoader;

        public PackageIntentReceiver(AppListLoader loader) {
            mLoader = loader;
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED);
            filter.addDataScheme("package");
            mLoader.getContext().registerReceiver(this, filter);
            // Register for events related to sdcard installation.
            IntentFilter sdFilter = new IntentFilter();
            sdFilter.addAction(IntentCompat.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE);
            sdFilter.addAction(IntentCompat.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE);
            mLoader.getContext().registerReceiver(this, sdFilter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Tell the loader about the change.
            mLoader.onContentChanged();
        }
    }

    /**
     * A custom Loader that loads all of the installed applications.
     */
    public static class AppListLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<AppEntry>> {
        final InterestingConfigChanges mLastConfig = new InterestingConfigChanges();
        final PackageManager mPm;

        List<AppEntry> mApps;
        PackageIntentReceiver mPackageObserver;

        public AppListLoader(Context context) {
            super(context);

            // Retrieve the package manager for later use; note we don't
            // use 'context' directly but instead the save global application
            // context returned by getContext().
            mPm = getContext().getPackageManager();
        }

        /**
         * This is where the bulk of our work is done.  This function is
         * called in a background thread and should generate a new set of
         * data to be published by the loader.
         */
        @Override
        public List<AppEntry> loadInBackground() {
            // Retrieve all known applications.
            List<ApplicationInfo> apps = mPm.getInstalledApplications(
                PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES |
                PackageManager.GET_DISABLED_COMPONENTS);
            if (apps == null) {
                apps = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
            }

            final Context context = getContext();

            // Create corresponding array of entries and load their labels.
            List<AppEntry> entries = new ArrayList<AppEntry>(apps.size());
            for (int i=0; i<apps.size(); i++) {
                AppEntry entry = new AppEntry(this, apps.get(i));
                entry.loadLabel(context);
                entries.add(entry);
            }

            // Sort the list.
            Collections.sort(entries, ALPHA_COMPARATOR);

            // Done!
            return entries;
        }

        /**
         * Called when there is new data to deliver to the client.  The
         * super class will take care of delivering it; the implementation
         * here just adds a little more logic.
         */
        @Override
        public void deliverResult(List<AppEntry> apps) {
            if (isReset()) {
                // An async query came in while the loader is stopped.  We
                // don't need the result.
                if (apps != null) {
                    onReleaseResources(apps);
                }
            }
            List<AppEntry> oldApps = apps;
            mApps = apps;

            if (isStarted()) {
                // If the Loader is currently started, we can immediately
                // deliver its results.
                super.deliverResult(apps);
            }

            // At this point we can release the resources associated with
            // 'oldApps' if needed; now that the new result is delivered we
            // know that it is no longer in use.
            if (oldApps != null) {
                onReleaseResources(oldApps);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Handles a request to start the Loader.
         */
        @Override
        protected void onStartLoading() {
            if (mApps != null) {
                // If we currently have a result available, deliver it
                // immediately.
                deliverResult(mApps);
            }

            // Start watching for changes in the app data.
            if (mPackageObserver == null) {
                mPackageObserver = new PackageIntentReceiver(this);
            }

            // Has something interesting in the configuration changed since we
            // last built the app list?
            boolean configChange = mLastConfig.applyNewConfig(getContext().getResources());

            if (takeContentChanged() || mApps == null || configChange) {
                // If the data has changed since the last time it was loaded
                // or is not currently available, start a load.
                forceLoad();
            }
       }

        /**
         * Handles a request to stop the Loader.
         */
        @Override
        protected void onStopLoading() {
            // Attempt to cancel the current load task if possible.
            cancelLoad();
        }

        /**
         * Handles a request to cancel a load.
         */
        @Override
        public void onCanceled(List<AppEntry> apps) {
            super.onCanceled(apps);

            // At this point we can release the resources associated with 'apps'
            // if needed.
            onReleaseResources(apps);
        }

        /**
         * Handles a request to completely reset the Loader.
         */
        @Override
        protected void onReset() {
            super.onReset();

            // Ensure the loader is stopped
            onStopLoading();

            // At this point we can release the resources associated with 'apps'
            // if needed.
            if (mApps != null) {
                onReleaseResources(mApps);
                mApps = null;
            }

            // Stop monitoring for changes.
            if (mPackageObserver != null) {
                getContext().unregisterReceiver(mPackageObserver);
                mPackageObserver = null;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Helper function to take care of releasing resources associated
         * with an actively loaded data set.
         */
        protected void onReleaseResources(List<AppEntry> apps) {
            // For a simple List<> there is nothing to do.  For something
            // like a Cursor, we would close it here.
        }
    }

    public static class AppListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AppEntry> {
        private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public AppListAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2);
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public void setData(List<AppEntry> data) {
            clear();
            if (data != null) {
                for (AppEntry appEntry : data) {
                    add(appEntry);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Populate new items in the list.
         */
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view;

            if (convertView == null) {
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_icon_text, parent, false);
            } else {
                view = convertView;
            }

            AppEntry item = getItem(position);
            ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.icon)).setImageDrawable(item.getIcon());
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(item.getLabel());

            return view;
        }
    }

    public static class AppListFragment extends SherlockListFragment
            implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<AppEntry>> {

        // This is the Adapter being used to display the list's data.
        AppListAdapter mAdapter;

        // If non-null, this is the current filter the user has provided.
        String mCurFilter;

        OnQueryTextListenerCompat mOnQueryTextListenerCompat;

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            // Give some text to display if there is no data.  In a real
            // application this would come from a resource.
            setEmptyText("No applications");

            // We have a menu item to show in action bar.
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            // Create an empty adapter we will use to display the loaded data.
            mAdapter = new AppListAdapter(getActivity());
            setListAdapter(mAdapter);

            // Start out with a progress indicator.
            setListShown(false);

            // Prepare the loader.  Either re-connect with an existing one,
            // or start a new one.
            getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            // Place an action bar item for searching.
            MenuItem item = menu.add("Search");
            item.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search);
            item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
            View searchView = SearchViewCompat.newSearchView(getActivity());
            if (searchView != null) {
                SearchViewCompat.setOnQueryTextListener(searchView,
                        new OnQueryTextListenerCompat() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                        // Called when the action bar search text has changed.  Since this
                        // is a simple array adapter, we can just have it do the filtering.
                        mCurFilter = !TextUtils.isEmpty(newText) ? newText : null;
                        mAdapter.getFilter().filter(mCurFilter);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                item.setActionView(searchView);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            // Insert desired behavior here.
            Log.i("LoaderCustom", "Item clicked: " + id);
           //Here i want to know the package name of the selected app item in the list
        }

        @Override
        public Loader<List<AppEntry>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
            // This is called when a new Loader needs to be created.  This
            // sample only has one Loader with no arguments, so it is simple.
            return new AppListLoader(getActivity());
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<AppEntry>> loader, List<AppEntry> data) {
            // Set the new data in the adapter.
            mAdapter.setData(data);

            // The list should now be shown.
            if (isResumed()) {
                setListShown(true);
            } else {
                setListShownNoAnimation(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<AppEntry>> loader) {
            // Clear the data in the adapter.
            mAdapter.setData(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155248/navigate-between-applications-at-android/24203373#24203373

I hope this one could give you some idea