# To filter out unwanted system apps from the OEM in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments

How can I get a list of non-system apps for my `RecyclerView`?

I want to filter my list not to include system apps

- The current app count for system apps is `353` but it should be around `15-20`
- I have used `packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0)`  to get the all the installed packages in the device and to differentiate between system apps and third party apps i have used
  `applicationInfo.flags` and `package.ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)==0`
- Here is a [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4REk.jpg)

Please help!!

Any language, `java` or `kotlin` is appreciated.
THANKS IN ADVANCE..

Comment: Besides "unwanted", what is the criteria for what you do and do not want in your list? For example, are you trying to create a launcher? If so, `getInstalledPackages()` is not the right approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non systems apps can be identified by having a `launch intent`
if the app has no launch intent then its a system app [check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18322300/8872691)

```java
ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> thirdPartyApps = new ArrayList<>();
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
for(ApplicationInfo packageInfo:packages){
    if( pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName) != null ){
                String currAppName = pm.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo).toString();
               //This app is a non-system app
               thirdPartyApps.add(packageInfo);
    }
    else{
        //System App
    }
}
```