# can user's of Android apps see the package name?

Tags: android

I'm new to Android development and was wondering if users can view the package name. Are the package names displayed on the store? or can they view them on their device?
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is way to get the package names of apps installed in the device using few lines of code. Check this answer for that http://stackoverflow.com/a/5097838/1567588. Not sure, whether you want a programmatic solution or just some general information. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm new to Android development and was wondering if users can view the
>   package name

There's an app that you can view the package name, like Process Managers, Task Killers.

> Are the package names displayed on the store? or can they view them on
>   their device?

No, but they can use that package name to search an app

Answer (score 0):

yes, users can see your package name on their device
and if users search on Play, your package name will in the result

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

But what do you want actually ?

Hide the package name or display it ?

Hide it is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems android os does not allow package display and you have to use a separate app like [Android SYstem Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.electricsheep.asi).