# Getting a list of selected app to open in another app

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an app that will show selected app in a list view. I found this link [How to get a list of installed android applications and pick one to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run) but it only show all the app installed on the device. 
All I want to show is all the app that I made that I installed on my device. So I wonder if I can select them one by one using package name or app name and then put it on a list view using package manager?

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: do you mean you want to get all the user installed app or app that you made ( app that you wrote as com.myapps.*) ?

Comment: yes! only the app that I made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you can do, filter package containing your package name:

```
    List<PackageInfo> packs = context.getPackageManager() 
            .getInstalledPackages(0); 

    public static final String MY_APP_PATTERN="com.myapps";

    for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) { 
        PackageInfo packageInfo = packs.get(i); 
        if (((packs.get(i).applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1)) { 
            continue; 
        } 

       if(packageInfo.packageName.contains(MY_APP_PATTERN)){
           Lod.d(DEBUG_TAG,"This package belongs to me: "+packageInfo.packageName)

           packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel( 
                context.getPackageManager()).toString(); 
           packageInfo.packageName; 
           packageInfo.versionCode; 
           packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(context 
                .getPackageManager())
       }
    }
```

You can also use your own pattern matcher to filter starting with.

Comment: but how can I only get who contains MY_APP_PATTERN?

Comment: try running the code and see it's output. Change MY_APP_PATTERN to your app package common name.

Comment: wow this really works! thanks man accepting and voting your answer right away!

Comment: One more question sir how can I also get the app icon using that condition?

Comment: Ofcourse, you can do whatever you desire to do with it. One suggestion: As some developers doesn't follow standard icon sizes, please use fix height/width for your imageView.