# I want to check whether android app is installed or not or get list of all apps installed through google play store

Tags: php, android, google-play-services, google-api-php-client

Hi I have downloaded google api php client. I want to authenticate user using his/her google android login and then check either a respective android app is installed on his phone against the matching email address that he logged in using google api.
or atleast get list of all apps that are installed on his phone using google api client.

I am not able to find specific function and its respective parameters. Please anyone point me to this.
At this point I am able to get user successfully authenticated and i get a valid token.

Now I need which webservice to call and with what parameters to pass to achieve the above.

Please suggest me step wise.

Also please check this URL where I am passing package name of Temple Run. I am not able to find the correct format in which I would pass access token that I receive from successful google account login.

https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/applications/com.imangi.templerun/

All I want to display the user on my webpage that the temple run app is installed on his/her phone

[this returns response in JSON]

Thanking in advance.

Comment: Check first part of the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run

Comment: I am trying to use server side scripting language such as php or jsp or aspt.net and get list of apps installed against google android id

Comment: Can you post your PHP code that you have written so far?