# How to get app icon from app name

Tags: android

I'm having some troubles getting other app's icon from the app name.
The only solution I found is to get app icon from the packet name.
However, I only have the string for the app name right now.

Is it possible to retrieve other installed app's icon from the app name?
Please help me with this. Your answer will be a great help, thanks.

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: Normally, application names/labels are localized. E.g., application name will be different string in English and in Russian. So, there is no way to know which application is using what name in which locale. Therefore, it is not possible to get application icon based on only its name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible with app name. Application name is nothing just name in Android. U need package name which is unique among all apps in any android device. Two different apps can have same name, but its not possible that two different apps have same package name. i hope ur clear

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the applications (see [How to get a list of installed android applications and pick one to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run)), get their name using their application info (`PackageManager.getApplicationLabel`), and if you find the name, you can get it's package name, from which you can get the application icon.