# How to go to "apps page" with intent

Tags: android, android-intent, launcher

I am trying to go back to "apps page"
like this: [image]
<sub>(source: [sbnation.com](http://assets.sbnation.com/assets/2359015/20120320-DSC06062.jpg))</sub>

using intent.

The problem is I am setting a button on my application and I don't know how go to back to "apps page"(not mean "home" here).

What should I do to fix this?

```
mButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.?);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Edit: If I launcher my app on "home page", how do I also go to back to "apps page" with this button?

Comment: Check this question: [How to get a list of installed android applications and pick one to run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run)

Comment: You can't. There is no such thing as an "apps page" in Android. A launcher night provide an "apps page" but then the intent to open it, if any, would depend on which launcher is installed.