# How do I know if a specific app is installed using Adobe Air on Android

Tags: android, actionscript, air, adobe

I would like to code a function which will let me know if another specific app of my company is installed on the current device. I guess that in order to do so I need to retrieve a list of the installed apps like here (Answer for native coders):

[How to get a list of installed android applications...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run)

Is there a straight forward way to get the list with action script?
Bottom line, I just need to know about my own apps. Maybe a way to get a list of air apps installed?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer no, but you can use one of the following:

1- Write a file in specific location indicates that the app from your company installed, and check this file from your app, to do this
   - On the first time run of the application write a file in the desktopDirectory:

```
var myAppTextFile:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("MyAppVersion.txt");
var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
fs.open(myAppTextFile, FileMode.WRITE);
fs.writeUTF("MyApp V0.0 installed");
fs.close();`
```

- Each time you run the New Application check this file:

  var myAppTextFile:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("MyAppVersion.txt");
                  var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
                  fs.open(myAppTextFile, FileMode.READ);
                  var str:String = fs.readUTF();
                  fs.close();`

  Note: Works for Android not for iOS.

2- Use Native extension to do this.

Comment: Thanks. Option 2 is obvious, option 1 is unclear for me. Can I actually access a common folder on Android (and iOS? I need both) write a file there using app A and access it from app B?

Comment: yes you can, i am using File.DesktopDirectory to write/read files and folders, i will share some code when i return to home :)

Comment: Doesn't let me write to  File.applicationDirectory. Did you test it on an Android device? File.applicationDirectory is a read-only folder.

Comment: File.desktopDirectory worked! Was able to access the same file from 2 different apps.
Will edit the answer.

Comment: @mik you are right it should be desktopDirectory, thanks for your edit :)