# ApplicationAdapter error when trying to get installed apps

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, android-scrollable-tabs

I am have scrollable tabs in my action bar and in one of those tabs I am trying to get a list of user installed apps and used system apps, like Flipoard, youtube, messaging etc. (eventually in alphabetical order)

I am trying to follow these, but I am having some errors implementing it because I am using fragments.

[How to get a list of installed android applications and pick one to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run)

http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-get-list-of-installed-apps-in-android

http://techblogon.com/get-installed-applications-list-android-example/

This is what I have for my Fragment:

```
package com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app.ApplicationAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class InstalledAppActivity extends Fragment
        implements OnItemClickListener {

    PackageManager packageManager;
    ListView apkList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_installed, container, false);
        packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();


        /*To filter out System apps*/

        apkList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.applist);

        new LoadApplications().execute();


        return rootView;
    }

    /**
     * Return whether the given PackageInfo represents a system package or not.
     * User-installed packages (Market or otherwise) should not be denoted as
     * system packages.
     *
     * @parampkgInfo
     * @return boolean
     */
/*    private boolean isSystemPackage(ApplicationInfo pkgInfo) {
        return ((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) ? true
                : false;
    }*/


// Don't need in Fragment
/*@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.block, menu);
   // super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}*/

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    }


    private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        List<ApplicationInfo> packageList1 = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            List<ApplicationInfo> packages = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);



            for(ApplicationInfo pi : packages) {

                packageList1.add(pi);


            }

            //sort by application name

            final PackageItemInfo.DisplayNameComparator comparator = new PackageItemInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager);

            /*Collections.sort(packageList1, new Comparator<PackageInfo>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(PackageInfo lhs, PackageInfo rhs) {
                    return comparator.compare(lhs.applicationInfo, rhs.applicationInfo);
                }
            });*/

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(InstalledAppActivity.this.getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading your apps...");
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            apkList.setAdapter(new ApplicationAdapter(getActivity(), packageList1, packageManager));

            if (pDialog.isShowing()){
                pDialog.dismiss();

        }


            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }

}
```

and this here is my ArrayAdapter class:

```
package com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.R;

import java.util.List;
public class ApplicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo> {
    private List<ApplicationInfo> appsList = null;
    private Context context;
    private PackageManager packageManager;

    public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, List<ApplicationInfo> textViewResourceId,
                              PackageManager appsList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, appsList);
        this.context = context;
        this.appsList = (List<ApplicationInfo>) appsList;
        packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.size() : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationInfo getItem(int position) {
        return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.get(position) : null);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (null == view) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.snippet_list_row, null);
        }

        ApplicationInfo data = appsList.get(position);
        if (null != data) {
            TextView appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
            TextView packageName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_package);
            ImageView iconview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);

            appName.setText(data.loadLabel(packageManager));
            packageName.setText(data.packageName);
            iconview.setImageDrawable(data.loadIcon(packageManager));
        }
        return view;
    }
};
```

This is the current error I am getting.

[image]

I am not sure what I should do to resolve this error and successfully get a list of user installed and used system apps in alphabetical order in all in a fragment.

What can be done about my approach and how can I achieve this?

Comment: Look at the last two parameters of your constructor: `List<ApplicationInfo> textViewResourceId, PackageManager appsList`. Given that the identifiers are apt descriptions of the expected parameters for the `super`'s constructor, do those types make sense?

Answer (score 0):

One of the arguments you're passing to the constructor of the `super` class, that is an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html), does not match with any of the ArrayAdapter's constructors.

I believe that argument is the the `PackageManager appsList`, you should instead pass a `List<T> appsList` to match the constructor defined [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E)).

Comment: I am not sure why that created an error in my onPostExecute when setting my adapter