# Android: launcher app that doesn't act as home screen?

Tags: android

I am customizing an Android ROM for work. We are creating a GPS device and need to lock users from using any other apps. In doing so, I have removed the default home screen and replaced it with my own.

I need an app launcher that will not act as a home screen. This is needed for testing and developing purposes and will be removed in the release. I'm sure one exists, I just don't know how to find it. Thanks!

Comment: Asking for app recommendations is off-topic for SO. That said, it'd be easy enough to just create an additional launcher component for your app, and remove it before release. You might check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run

Comment: Oh, sorry. There's so many subdomains of this site... I guess I will just do that then. Thanks.