# How to make a launcher search apps

Tags: android, search

I want my launcher to be able to search the apps through a search dialog. I already have the xml and everything done, just not the search. I want to use a search dialog.

Comment: I would think you can query to find the list of apps on the device and just search that list. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2696617/371018

Comment: @ariets Thats what i have been trying to do. Everytime i do that, my brain hurts. I cant think straight.

Comment: @ariets i already have that code and the aplications appear and function properly. What i want to do is add a searchbox that the user can use to search the names in.

Comment: @ariets gave the answer on how to query what's installed... what problem are you having with that?

Comment: @Buddy i want my app's textbox to be able to find the app that is written in it.

Comment: Ok, take a look at [this code](http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon), it shows how to get a list of installed applications... then just loop over that and compare against the `appname`.