# launcher which will show only seletec application. restrict other apps

Tags: android, android-intent, android-viewpager, launcher

I want to make  launcher app retreive/store a list of selected application and restrict other applications.and the list of the application should me in viewpager (ex. Horizontal manner).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have tried http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/how-to-write-custom-launcher-app-in-android/ this ..but the the view of applications are coming in vertically. i want that the application list should come horizontally or like viewpager.

Comment: Please update your question with what ever you have tried. It will help viewer to understand your situation more

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not a question, but a request.
Now, to help you out - there is around 50 apps which restrict showing apps in any launcher, no reason to make another launcher.. BUT. If you still want to do it, when making the list in the adapter, just remove the ones with packages you want to hide.

Comment: thanks actually i want to make a launcher which will show only selected applications in that launcher. and when viewing that application on the layout . those layout should swipe able left and right

Comment: @AbhishekPunia Here is how you list all apps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5097838/2102748
and the official guideline to creating swipe-able layouts: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html
Hope that helps.