# Get list of applications which can share data

Tags: android, android-package-managers

This code shows default share dialog

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/html");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Message"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));
```

[image: share dialog]

Question: Instead of showing the list of applications in the default system dialog, I want to get the list of applications and show them in my custom list.

Comment: please explain *i want to show list of apps in my activity grid view not in this default dialog*

Comment: i want to get list of apps that can send message so that I can show it my activity..

Comment: try this link for get all installed apps on device http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the PackageManager with the Intent to get the list of applications which can listen to the SEND intent. From the list of applications returned, get the details you would like to display, eg. the icon, name, etc. You would need the package name to launch the app when the user clicks on it.

```
PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, null);
mainIntent.setType("text/plain");
List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0); // returns all applications which can listen to the SEND Intent
for (ResolveInfo info : resolveInfos) {
    ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = info.activityInfo.applicationInfo;

    //get package name, icon and label from applicationInfo object and display it in your custom layout 

    //App icon = applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);
    //App name  = applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
    //App package name = applicationInfo.packageName;
}
```

After you have this set of application details, you can use this in the Adapter of your GridView and show the details.

Answer (score 0):

So instead of the usual popup that shows applications in a list you want a custom popup that shows the applications in a grid view?

This is possible by creating a popup with a grid view yourself. Regardless of it being a share action.
Then build a list of applications you would like to show. You can get these using the [`resolveActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#resolveActivity%28android.content.pm.PackageManager%29) method from `Intent` (or see Swayam's answer).
Then use that list to populate the grid view.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add query in your AdroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest>
 
 <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
<application
 />
<manifest/>
```