# Permission issue in Samsung Galaxy phones for all installed apps

Tags: android

Permission issue in Samsung Galaxy phones for all installed apps. anybody help me how to list all installed apps in Samsung galaxy phone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run

Comment: Is this code is working on Samsung devices ? Because Samsung doesn't gave you a permission for retrieving installed apps.