# how to open installed application from my application for sharing contents

Tags: java, android, share-intent

I need to open all applications installed in my phone into my android application for sharing contents, can I find a simple method ?

Comment: which App you want to open? you must know it's package name to open it

Comment: All applications installed on that android phone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a list of installed android applications and pick one to run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try this if data is in text format

```
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";

    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);


    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is un-clear. But I think I got your question.

You want to share some data?

you have to Use `share Intent`

Here is Example-

**Share Text Data**-

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

**Share Image**

```
String fileName = "image-3116.jpg";//Name of an image
String externalStorageDirectory =     Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
String myDir = externalStorageDirectory + "/saved_images/"; // the file will be in saved_images
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///" + myDir + fileName);
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/html");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Deal"));
```

Comment: If the question is unclear, please flag as such, don't answer. I might read and understand it differently and give a completely different answer.

Comment: @Adriaan you are right but I understood what sree want. So I gave Answer, that is better to flag.