# Stop BroadCastReceiver from triggering on Application update in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I have to show prompt when a new Application is installed or uninstalled in the device,so far its working fine. The only problem is prompt is coming even when Application is updated. 
How to stop `BroadCastReceiver` from triggering on Application update.

```
<receiver android:name=".WeepingReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="100">
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />

         <data android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**BroadCast**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL)
            || intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)) {
            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, NewAppActivity.class).
            setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).putExtra(Utility.NEW_PACKAGE_NAME, packageName));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if (extras.containsKey(Intent.EXTRA_REPLACING) && extras.getBoolean(Intent.EXTRA_REPLACING))
{
//do nothing here it is condition of updating your existing app
}else
{
//do your code here
}
```

Comment: The above solution worked for me thanks. But now I am getting the activity when app is uninstalled. How to handle that ? Please tell

Comment: Just check remove condition as :
  if (extras.containsKey(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED) && extras.getBoolean(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED)){

} and do nothing in this condition or write your condition as suitable to you.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to change your if condition as

```
if (!intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED) &&
       (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED))) {

      context.startActivity(new Intent(context, NewAppActivity.class)
          .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
          .putExtra(Utility.NEW_PACKAGE_NAME, packageName));
}
```

And manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".WeepingReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="100">
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
         <data android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: `PACKAGE_REPLACED` he doesn't want hat

Comment: @TimCastelijns see my if condition there is check of not update condition , condition will never be true in case of updating application , fisst clearly check whole solution don't be smart to just give down vote on other's answer.

Comment: @TimCastelijns thnks

Answer (score 0):

Application Update is re-installing a new app so it is correct that your receiver receives the event as `PACKAGE_ADDED`. Thus, you cannot stop your broadcast from receiving the event.

However, you can validate if the intent is being updated by checking whether the package name was there before. You can have a list of installed apps' package names and store. Then check as you are doing:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL)
            || intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)
            || !packageList.contains(packageName))
```

[You could get your package list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5097838/6011938) by:

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
//get a list of installed apps.
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
   packageList.add(packageInfo.packageName);
}
```