# How to open an installed app from another application using voice command on android

Tags: android, voice-recognition

So I am trying to build a virtual assistant on android. Currently i am trying to implement the logic to open another app using voice command. I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run) and tried implementing the same code but it is giving me an exception saying `Unknown package: PackageName`. So if I say "open facebook" then it says `Unknown package: facebook`. I can't figure out why this code is not working!

```
try {
     if(text.contains("open") || text.contains("launch") || text.contains("play")) {
         speech = text.split(" ", 2);
         String appName = speech[1];
         PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
         String pkgName = pm.getInstallerPackageName(appName);
         Intent launchApp = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(pkgName);
         startActivity(launchApp);
     } 
} catch (Exception ex) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

**Edit:** I got help from answer # 6 on the question which i mentioned.

Comment: probably because facebook isnt the package name. its probably com.facebook.katana

Comment: I also tried with other apps e.g. WhatsApp, Camera, Contacts etc.

Comment: did they work? 'facebook' is not a package name.

Comment: They didn't work either!

Comment: What do you mean 'facebook' is not a package name?

Comment: I told you what I meant on my first comment. What's the package name of your app? Facebook is the NAME of the app. For example, the name of my app is fuhnatik. But the package name is com.fuhnatik.xxxxxxxxx