# Is it possible to hide an app, so that it can‘t be „seen“ by other apps in this list?

Tags: android

With`getPackageManager()` it is possible to get a list of installed Android applications. ([How to get a list of installed android applications and pick one to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run/47329868#47329868))

Is it possible to hide an Android app, so that it **can‘t be seen** by other apps in this list? (For example, because an app can reveal the political orientation, the sexual orientation or the health status of a user).

Comment: why are you wanting to hide an application? not a good look.

Comment: For this reason: "... because an app can reveal the political orientation, the sexual orientation or the health status of a user". 

And that's why it seems difficult to me that every android app can see the entire list of installed apps without having any permission from the user. 
Does this make sense?

Comment: yes it makes sense.... but there are ways around this. for example, override the onPause, onStop, or onDestory to either send the user out of the protected activity, or make the user enter a pin to access it. hiding it wont look good.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to hide an Android app, so that it can‘t be „seen“ by other apps in this list?

No.

> because an app can reveal the political orientation, the sexual orientation or the health status of a user

Another reason for this would be "because an app is malware", which is why you cannot hide apps this way.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Only apps listed as malware can be hidden this way, and don't think that it's a good idea to hide any app from the launcher.

Comment: "Only apps listed as malware can be hidden this way," 
I see :) Thanks.