# Is it possible for an iOS app so the a list of other installed apps?

Tags: ios

With „getPackageManager“ it is possible to get a list of installed applications on Android. 
([How to get a list of installed android applications and pick one to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run/47329868#47329868))

But: Is it also possible for apps to see a list of installed apps on iOS smartphones? And if yes, is it possible to hide an iOS app, so that it can‘t be „seen“ by other apps in this list?

Comment: Not with any public APIs, no.

Comment: Yes for private apps. No for apps from the App Store. A [simple search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+list+installed+apps) would have told you this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get a complete list of all apps installed, but if you know what you are looking for, you CAN (probably) check if a specific app is installed by testing if you can open that app's URL:

```
let otherAppURL = ...
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(otherAppURL)
{
    // It's installed
}
else
{
    // It's not installed
}
```

Comment: Don't forget you need to add the URL scheme to the Info.plist before you can use `canOpenURL`.