# How to make a dialog like in Google Photos?

Tags: android, dialog, share

In Google photos or youtube, [image]there is this kind of share dialog:

I want to create something like this for my app. My problem lies in making something that appears at the bottom of the screen and that you can drag up. I have everything else working, but I can't manage to create a dialog that you can expand like this. How is it possible?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send

Comment: @SarthakGandhi the thing is I want to make my own share menu, just like Youtube and Google Photos don't use the one that android uses!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run

Comment: @SarthakGandhi As I have already said, my problem is making this dialog that will appear start at the bottom, and be pullable up the screen.

Comment: Even i searched a lot about it, but i think they are using a custom dialog apart from what they provide in the android api.