# How to detect if specific app can show ads

Tags: android, admob, ads

I am implementing an android application which checks whether an installed application can show ads or not.
What is the safest way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no guaranteed way to do that. After all, an ad is text or an image, and pretty much every app shows text and/or images.

Comment: yes but there must some way to check if app uses adsense or admob, etc

Answer (score 2):

### Get All Applicaitons that are installed.

```java
   final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
   List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

### Check The Appstore using the app id to check if it `has ads`

**Home Page For Apps:** `https://play.google.com/store/apps?hl=en`

**App Page:** `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bandainamcogames.dbzdokkanww&hl=en`

just replace the id's value of `com.bandainamcogames.dbzdokkanww` with the app package from the packages list

then check the page for "**Contains Ads**"
[image]

Refs:

- [Get All Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run)

Comment: The string to search is `<div class="bSIuKf">Contains Ads`

Answer (score -1):

An ad is an element from the Web. Every element loaded from the web is essentially a HTTP request. You could implement in your application some mechanism to check the HTTP requests generated in real time by other applications and block them.